# Facing a Multithreading stacktrace - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: java, multithreading

I am facing the issue of trying to monitor a directory (using the Java 7 Watcher Service) and FTP any new files over to another machine.

I have it running and 'sometimes' functional, but it looks as though I am running into a threading issue.  My watcher service seems to be holding onto a file that I'm trying to get the content of with another Thread.  I'm tried using Process Explorer, but I cannot find the originating process.

I can paste the code below (again) if you wish.  Anyone have any idea's on how to debug this issue I am facing

EDIT.  HERE'S THE CODE:

```
public class WatchDir implements Runnable{

...
...
   void processEvents() {

        for (;;) {

            // wait for key to be signalled
            WatchKey key;
            try {
                key = watcher.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                return;
            }

            Path dir = keys.get(key);
            if (dir == null) {
                System.err.println("WatchKey not recognized!!");
                continue;
            }

            for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
                WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();

                // Context for directory entry event is the file name of entry
                WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(event);
                Path name = ev.context();
                Path child = dir.resolve(name);

                if(!Files.isDirectory(child, NOFOLLOW_LINKS)){
                    //Callable<LftFile> worker;

                    try {
                        this.file = new LftFile(child.toFile(), kind != ENTRY_CREATE);  <-- RIGHT HERE
                        // ADD TO FTP method
                    } catch ...
...
...


LftFile's method that causes issue:

    public long getfileHash(File f) {
        long crc = -1;
        try ( InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f) ) {   <-- This FIS is causing it
            CRC32 crcMaker = new CRC32();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int bytesRead;
            while((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                crcMaker.update(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            crc = crcMaker.getValue();  
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
            logger.error("File Not Found {}", fnf);

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            logger.error("File IOException {}", ioe);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("File IOException {}", e);
        }       
        return crc;
    }
```

Comment: What operating system, windows?

Comment: Yes, please paste the code, and specify the line you're getting the problem. Depending on what you're doing you could just catch and ignore the exception or do something else about it.

Comment: yes, windows on my dev box, then off to CentOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is that you can't have the same file to be opened by two processes at the same time; One process is the one adding (and writing) the new file to your directory, and the other one (your program) trying to open it to read it and calculate a hash from it.

The best thing you could do is to catch the exception and retry after a couple of seconds when the file is free to open exclusively by your program.

UPDATE

Having a look at your code, I think adding a try-error approach is easy, just do something like this in your code:

```
boolean sucess = false;
while(!success) {
    try {
        this.file = new LftFile(child.toFile(), kind != ENTRY_CREATE);
        sucess = true;
        // ADD TO FTP method
    } catch (IOException e) { // or a more explicit exception rather than a generic IOException
        Thread.sleep(1000); // Wait for a second
        sucess = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I avoid having the two processes try and open/read at the same time?  Where can I synchronize?

Comment: It is not trivial synchronizing two processes (not the same as two threads), specially if you don't have control over one of them. So instead of trying to synchronize the access to a file, a try-and-error technique is more suitable in these cases.

Comment: "The problem you have is that you can't have the same file to be opened by two processes at the same time;" <-- uh, this is no problem under Unix

Comment: @fge maybe not if you have the code of both programs and can control the flags used in the system call `open()`, but in @Dan 's  case this is the problem.

Comment: Almost works... I get an error every now and then however.  Trying to debug now

Comment: Unfort. that's not fixing it.  I'm still getting that same error

Comment: Can we continue this in a chat?: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49439/facing-a-multithreading-stacktrace

Comment: Got it finally... Thanks!   I appreciate your help with this